# Issue with reset and tie function in TicTacToe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built a simple tic tac toe game and its working well. I want to implement a reset button and a tie function but I cant seem to wrap my code around it.

I understand that reset is easy with location.reload but I dont know where to wrap it in my jquery.

I am stumped on where to return for a tie in my functions as well.
Here is my code

```
<div id = "gameboard">
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square bottom right sq1"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom right sq2"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom sq3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square bottom right sq4"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom right sq5"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom sq6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square right sq7"></div>
    <div class = "square right sq8"></div>
    <div class = "square sq9"></div>
  </div>
  <button type ="reset">reset</button>
</div>

</body>

<script>
//use doc.ready to wrap functions after page loads
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create a player 1 to test
    var player = 1;

    //make a click event for the class sqaures
    $('.square').on("click", function(event){

        //store the square class into $(this)
        var squareSelected = $(this);
        //make an if else statenent that adds the class "x" || "o" to your html to show it has been selected
        if(squareSelected.hasClass("fa fa-times fa-4x") || squareSelected.hasClass("fa fa-circle-o fa-4x")){
            alert("you have clicked here already!")
        } else {
            //when square has been selected by player 1 set the player to 2;vice versa
            if(player===1){
                squareSelected.addClass("fa fa-times fa-4x");
                if (checkWin("fa fa-times fa-4x")){
                    alert("Congrats! Player " + player + " has WON!")
                } else {
                player = 2;
                }
            } else {
                squareSelected.addClass("fa fa-circle-o fa-4x");
                if (checkWin("fa fa-circle-o fa-4x")){
                    alert("Congrats! Player " + player + " has WON!")
                } else {
                player = 1;

                }
            }
        }
    });

    //check if player won
    //if player has 3 across,3 up/down, or 3 diagnal they win
    function checkWin(symbol){
        if($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq3").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq7").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Here is a Jsfiddle for this code

Comment: jsfiddle.net/mip12793/3tL201zL/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for a tie with this test:

```
$(".fa-times, .fa-circle-o").length == 9
```

Perform that test in the `else` block of the `if (checkWin(...))` statement.

To clear the board:

```
$(".square").removeClass("fa-times fa-circle fa fa-4x");
```

You could put that in a click handler for a "reset" button.

There are several other improvements you could apply to your code:

- Avoid repetition of code for the case when player is 1 or 2: use a variable for the class to add, and toggle the `player` value with `player = 3 - player`
- Flatten your code, by using `return` to exit the function when nothing more should happen
- Apply the `fa` and `fa-4x` already from the start (in the HTML) to each square, so you don't need to manage that any more in your code.
- Remove the `sq1`, `sq2`,... classes, as you can reference each square separately with the `$('.square').get(i)` jQuery method
- Use `.is()` to check for several classes in one call
- Use `some` and `every` array methods for shorter code to test for a win.
- Add a test so that the user cannot continue clicking after the game was already a win.

Here is the code after applying these changes. Note that I have made the grid smaller just for this snippet (by changing CSS for `square`, and using `fa-2x` instead of `fa-4x`):

```js
// In HTML: already assign classes fa and fa-4x, so you don't need to manage
//          those anymore.
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = 1;
    // Define the classes that are used for the two symbols
    var symbols = ['fa-times', 'fa-circle-o'];
    // Get collection of the 9 squares
    var $squares = $(".square");
    // Set the filter to be used to identify occupied square(s)
    var occupied = "." + symbols.join(", .");

    $('.square').on("click", function(event){
        // Add a test to avoid play continues after game already ended
        if (!player) {
            alert("Game is already over. Click reset to start a new game.")
            return;
        }
        var squareSelected = $(this);
        // Use .is() for shorter syntax, only testing two classes
        if(squareSelected.is(occupied)){
            alert("you have clicked here already!");
            return; // Exit, to make rest of code more flat
        }
        // Get name of class to use:
        var symbol = symbols[player-1];
        squareSelected.addClass(symbol);
        if (checkWin(symbol)){
            alert("Congrats! Player " + player + " has WON!");
            player = 0; // Avoid that play continues in this state.
            return; // Exit, to make rest of code more flat
        }
        // Test for a tie
        if ($squares.filter(occupied).length == 9) {
            alert("Game over. It is a tie.");
            player = 0; // Avoid that play continues in this state.
            return;
        }
        // Toggle player between 1 and 2:
        player = 3 - player;
    });

    function checkWin(symbol){
        // Use more generic & functional code to test for 3-in-a-row 
        var lines = [
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
        ];
        // Return whether some of the lines have the symbol in every cell 
        return lines.some(function (line) {
            return line.every(function (i) {
                return $squares.eq(i).hasClass(symbol);
            });
        });
    }
    
    $('#reset').click(function reset() {
        player = 1;
        // Remove all symbols
        $(".square").removeClass(symbols.join(" "));
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster");
body {
    background-color: #21c6be;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
    text-align: center;
    color: #c621b3;
    background-color: #236d72;
}

#gameboard {
    width: 360px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

.row {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: crosshair;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

button {
    color: #c621b3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/703129f3e9.js"></script>

<!--<h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>-->
<div id = "gameboard">
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x bottom right"></div>
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x bottom right"></div>
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x bottom right"></div>
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x bottom right"></div>
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x right"></div>
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x right"></div>
    <div class = "square fa fa-2x"></div>
  </div>
  <button id ="reset" type ="reset">reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @trinicot unfortunate both methods do not work. The first when i pair with an alert notifies me after each click and the seconds keeps the board empty from the get go.

Comment: Do you have fiddle that is complete (including the CSS)? There must be some part of the code that is not in your question, because the first test would be `1 == 9` after the first move as there is no way you would have 9 occurrences of these two classes combined.

Comment: @trinicot and I am also using the skeleton framework too.

Comment: I was able to fix the reset button I used location.reload() in my if else function for the players

Comment: I fixed an issue in my answer (had to add a dot before class name in selector), and added more recommendations and a working snippet.

Comment: one last question. I want to add a form for submit two player names but the player variable in js is set to a single variable. Would I be able to tie that to two players with set names?

Comment: Use an array: `names = ["Jeff", "Helen"];` and then address the correct entry with `names[player-1]`.

Comment: $("#submit").submit(function(){
    var names = [$("#player1").val,$("#player2").val]
    }) // So i have these retrieving from my html and stored in the names array. are you saying to replaces the player variables with the names[i]?

Comment: You need to *call* `val`, so add parentheses. You use your alternating `player` variable to retrieve the corresponding name from the `names` array with `names[player - 1]`. Watch out that you do not store that array in variable that only exists in the submission callback... But please try a bit more. And if you really cannot make it work, ask a new question.

Comment: For some reason when I add it to the alternating variables it breaks the code all together. Sorry I am still pretty new with JS/Jquery so this is the hardest project Iv had to date

Comment: The comments section is not intended for asking new questions. If you have a new problem then describe it in a new question, and provide the relevant details, code and what you tried and which error you get. There will be plenty of people who will have a look at it. I will too when I have time.

Comment: Sorry! ill do a little bit more research